# Unable to position matplotlib ax.annotate correctly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

in the below code, I'm trying to plot stacked bar chart of % of stoke events against the gender variable.

```
dfgender=df.groupby('gender')['stroke'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack().fillna(0)
ax=dfgender.plot.bar(stacked=True,colormap='tab10',figsize=(8, 6))
plt.legend(loc="upper right", ncol=1, prop={'size': 8})
plt.title('Gender vs Stroke')
plt.xlabel("Gender")
plt.ylabel("Proportion")
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(round(p.get_height(),2), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2, p.get_height()),ha='center',va='center',xytext=(10, 0), textcoords='offset points')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But as you can see, the placement of the bar labels is incorrect. 1 should be 5% and 0 should be 95%. I want the figures to be represented in percentages and be positioned in the center of the bars. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: You might consider upgrading your version of matplotlib and using [`bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html).

Comment: I'm using colab, is there a way to do that?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804), which also has links to many examples of **stacked** bars with labels.